# Angular CLI: how to run test and serve at the same time

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Is there a way to practice TDD and serving the app at the same time?
I mean something like `ng serve --run-tests`?
So every time I save a file(spec/non spec) it run the test first then serves the app. In this case it should rebuild and reload only if non spec files were modified, but I believe `ng serve` is doing that already.

Angular >= 4.3.0
Angular CLI >= 1.6.0

Comment: Open two terminals, run ng test in one, and ng serve in the other?

Comment: Using `concurrently` works but doesn't fulfill my entire problem. The tasks run out of order.